# sql bigquery time_diff

Tags: sql, bigquery

Как исправить ошибку в запросе?

```
SELECT time_diff ((SELECT MAX (commitTime) FROM `alert-vista-232907.WP.AS` LIMIT 1000), (SELECT MIN (commitTime) FROM `alert-vista-232907.WP.AS` LIMIT 1000))
```

No matching signature for `function TIME_DIFF` for argument types:

> FLOAT64, FLOAT64. Supported signature: TIME_DIFF(TIME, TIME,
>   DATE_TIME_PART) at [1:8]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT time_diff(MAX(commitTime), MIN(commitTime)) delta
FROM `alert-vista-232907.WP.AS`
```

Возможно, потребуется CAST() в тип TIME - ибо не указан DDL таблицы. Или наоборот - не нужен TIMEDIFF, достаточно вульгарного вычитания.